# Loading multiple codeigniter models with same function names causing overwriting?

Tags: codeigniter, models

If inside my controller's constructor, I load two different models for example,

```
$this->load->model('Pens_model');
$this->load->model('Pencils_model');
```

where each model extends MY_Model, and MY_Model has the following outline,

```
class MY_Model extends Model
{

protected static $tablename = "";
protected static $title = "";
protected static $idattribute = 'id';
    ...
    ...
    function getTableName(){
    return self::$tablename;
}
}
```

The pens model has:

```
class Pens_model extends My_model {

    function Pens_model(){
        parent::MY_Model();
        self::$tablename = "pens";
        self::$title = 'Pens';
    }
        ...
}
```

and the Pencils model has a similar constructor with tablename as '*pencils*'.

Now the controller's index function has the following,

```
echo $this->Pens_model->getTableName()."\n";
echo $this->Pencils_model->getTableName()."\n";
```

What I observe is that the table name of the model which was loaded last (pencils in this case) is printed out twice - as though the tablename and functions were being overwritten.
Is this a CI bug/limitation or an error in my implementation ?

Comment: It looks to me like Late static binding... what is the php version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> php ver<5.3

Static variables are shared throughout the inheritance tree which means:

You have extended model class with MY_Model.

Codeigniter first load `My_Model` and then loads extended classes `Pen_Model` and `Pencils_Model`.

You have defined `static $tablename` once in `My_Model` and both classes (`Pen_Model` and `Pencils_Model`) will use that same reference.

In that case value will be first "" (you want see this), than you will load `Pen_Model` and it will reference that same static tablename from parent class so value will be **Pen**. 
Then you will load `Pencils_Model` and value of table name will be `Pencils` (it is the same reference as the reference from class `Pen_Model`)
So.. when you echo those values it will show you last value that you have set and that is in your case **Pencils**.

> php ver>= 5.3

`static::` reference was introduced in php 5.3 to solve the issue of late static binding (it resolves to the static class called at runtime), but `self::` still refers to parent class, since a static call to self will be resolved at compile time.

Comment: I think I understand your explanation - but is there a clean solution around this though? (I have generic functions within MY_Model which rely on there being a $tablename and $title). Do php versions >= 5.3 fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Upgraded to 5.3.3, but this still didn't seem to work. What does seem to work is declaring the variables as 'const tablename=""'. and referring to it as static::tablename. Would this be php backwards compatible?

Comment: my bad.. My explanation was little bit misleading and wrong concerning version of php.. please read edited answer...

Comment: thanks for the clarification, found more details at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php too. For the sake of my project I just switched the fields to constants.